# Using && in Spring MVC @PreAuthorize

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-el

I need to use an && operator in a spring @PreAuthorize annotation as follows:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('AUTH_ADMIN') && isEnabled(principal.department, #docCat)")
@RequestMapping(value = "/samedept/patient/{pin}/results/{docCat}/{docResultType}/{docId}", method = RequestMethod.GET,
        headers = ContentTypeHeader.HEADER_APPLICATION_PDF)
ModelAndView secureViewResultPdf(@PathVariable(value = "pin") long pin,
                           @PathVariable(value = "docCat") String docCat,
                           @PathVariable(value = "docResultType") String docResultType,
                           @PathVariable(value = "docId") String docId);
```

I tried this but I'm getting

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot handle (38) '&'
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.Tokenizer.process(Tokenizer.java:193)
```

I've looked all over the web but can't find an example of an && operator used this way. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify `&&` to `and`, if the meaning of `&&` is `and`

Answer (score 2):

if you take a look at spel documentation in 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html
you will see that Larry.Z is right.

look at

> 6.5.6.2 Logical operators
>       // -- AND --

```
// evaluates to false
boolean falseValue = parser.parseExpression("true and false").getValue(Boolean.class);
```